# IBM Appcenter console apk fails to upload - Could not find android.aapt.dir

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

```html
[3/24/15 12:23:23:706 CDT] 00000098 AAPT          I   Resolving APK without AAPT\
[3/24/15 12:23:23:936 CDT] 00000098 UploadService E   Exception during resource                                                                                                  upload. null\
[3/24/15 12:23:23:937 CDT] 00000098 UploadService E   \{\
        "id": "86266e14-c273-4268-97a2-d1d6861e96d2",\
        "message": "FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.",\
        "productVersion": "6.1.0"\
\}\
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException\
        at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:735)\
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.putAll(UploadService.java:313                                                                                                 )\
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.fileUploaded(UploadService.ja                                                                                                 va:153)\
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.__fileUploadedJSON__(UploadSe                                                                                                 rvice.java:106)\
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                                 java:60)\
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                                 sorImpl.java:37)\
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRe                                                                                                 quest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandler.java:33)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHa                                                                                                 ndler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandler.java:34)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.ha                                                                                                 ndleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.ha                                                                                                 ndleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.ha                                                                                                 ndleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.ha                                                                                                 ndleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.ha                                                                                                 ndleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.ha                                                                                                 ndleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.hand                                                                                                 leRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequ                                                                                                 est(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleR                                                                                                 equest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRe                                                                                                 quest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(                                                                                                 ResourceInvocation.java:92)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.j                                                                                                 ava:76)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:26)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHa                                                                                                 ndlersChain.java:22)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(Abstrac                                                                                                 tHandlersChain.java:67)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHan                                                                                                 dlersChain.java:52)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithout                                                                                                 FaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(Reques                                                                                                 tProcessor.java:154)\
        at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServl                                                                                                 et.java:133)\
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper                                                                                                 .java:1230)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletW                                                                                                 rapper.java:779)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletW                                                                                                 rapper.java:478)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(Serv                                                                                                 letWrapperImpl.java:178)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppF                                                                                                 ilterChain.java:136)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilte                                                                                                 rChain.java:97)\
        at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterI                                                                                                 nstanceWrapper.java:195)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilte                                                                                                 rChain.java:91)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFil                                                                                                 terManager.java:960)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebA                                                                                                 ppFilterManager.java:1064)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(Cac                                                                                                 heServletWrapper.java:87)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:                                                                                                 909)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.j                                                                                                 ava:1662)\
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.jav                                                                                                 a:200)\
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimina                                                                                                 tion(HttpInboundLink.java:459)\
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest                                                                                                 (HttpInboundLink.java:526)\
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(H                                                                                                 ttpInboundLink.java:312)\
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboun                                                                                                 dLink.java:283)\
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDi                                                                                                 scriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)\
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete                                                                                                 (NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)\
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted                                                                                                 (AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)\
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFutu                                                                                                 re.java:217)\
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChanne                                                                                                 lFuture.java:161)\
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)\
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)\
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.j                                                                                                 ava:775)\
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)\
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)\
}
```

I am trying to upload an apt file to the IBM Appcenter console. It failed. Received this error in Server log while upload.

> [3/19/15 11:13:29:116 CDT] 00000099 AAPT          I   findAAPT: Could not find a  apt. Please set property android.aapt or android.aapt.dir.
>   [3/19/15 11:13:29:117 CDT] 00000099 AAPT          I   Resolving APK without AAPT
>   [3/19/15 11:13:29:528 CDT] 00000099 UploadService E   Exception during resource                                                                    upload. null
>   [3/19/15 11:13:29:531 CDT] 00000099 UploadService E   {
>           "id": "68c1578b-2580-4bf3-a5d6-ab248ec646d3",
>           "message": "FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.",
>           "productVersion": "6.1.0"
>   }

Followed the below steps to configure the android.aapt.dir on WebSphere ND.

1. Copy the WL_INSTALL_DIR/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk directory to a location in the config directory of the deployment manager's profile. This will be propagated to the servers through the file synchronization service; for example, WAS_INSTALL_DIR/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/cell-name/clusters/cluster-name/android-sdk.
2. Configure the environment entry android.aapt.dir with value ${USER_INSTALL_ROOT}/config/cells/cell-name/clusters/cluster-name/android-sdk.
3. Click System administration > Nodes, select the nodes, and click Full Synchronize.
   Syncronized the node and restarted the WebSphere Server. Still getting the same error while upload the apk.

[image: Screenshot of server configuration property - IBM Application Center Console]

Worklight Server Consumer Edition Version: Fix Pack 6.1.0.2 IF 20150223_1217

Answer (score 0):

First you should follow the correct user documentation topic. [This the is the topic for Worklight 6.1](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_appcenter_manually.html).

You should optionally edit your question with screen shots showing the setup you have done for step 9 (for Websphere ND).

Comment: Hi Idan. Thanks. I am aware of the document, it for 6.3. But both version the configuration steps remains same. Updated the question with steps i have done and screenshot of my app center server property configuration.

Comment: Hi Idan. Is redeployment of ApplicationCenter.war is required after the JNDI  property android.aapt.dir update.

Comment: Hi, details steps to fix this issue, will be a great help.

Comment: I don't have those. Add a trace.log to fully see what is happening so it could be debugged.

Comment: Hi, Emailed the SystemOut.log to your email. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73687/discussion-between-pvr-and-idan-adar).

Answer (score 0):

Note that android.aapt.dir should point to a folder that contains the subdirectories bin.linux-x86, bin.macosx-x86, bin.windows-x86. Those subdirectories are in tools/android-sdk of your installation.

If you are on a different operating system than Linux, MacOs or Windows, Worklight does not provide the aapt tool and some fallback code is executed. It could also be that when you copied the directory containing the aapt tool into WebSphere, the permissions got messed up and the aapt tool is no longer executable. Then the fallback code is also executed.

An alternative way is to set the aapt location via the JNDI property android.aapt. This should not point to the directory but to the tool itself.

To be on the safe side, note that in the description that you cite, the cell-name and cluster-name are just placeholders for the real names. You need to use the real names that represent your installation.

The stack trace that you mention is in the fallback code. It seems that the fallback code was not able to find or read the manifest file in the apk. Even though it is in general better to use the aapt tool when available (via setting android.aapt or android.aapt.dir), this requires further investigation. It could be that the uploaded APK file is corrupted or that the fallback code has a defect.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I set the JNDI to --/metlife/runtime/installed/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/instance01Cell01/android-sdk, and this folder has 777 permission. Still getting the same error.